# Is there a kdegames package alternative in 15.04

Tags: games, 15.04, kde-apps

The package `kdegames` is no longer available in Ubuntu 15.04.  Is there an alternative to the `kdegames` package in Ubuntu 15.04?

Prior to release 15.04, this package included a suite of KDE games, including KBlocks, KBounce, KGoldRunner, KMahjongg, KPat, KAtomic, KNetwalk, etc.

I see that the following packages are available in Vivid:

- `kdegames-card-data`
- `kdegames-mahjongg-data`
- `libkdegames6abi1`
- `libkdegamesprivate1abi1`

Does installing these packages install the "old" KDE4 suite of game applications, or do we need to install each game individually now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a list of the dependencies from Utopic. They're all available in Vivid, so I'm not sure why kdegames is gone.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/kdegames

- bomber (>= 4:4.11.3) arcade spaceship game
- bovo (>= 4:4.11.3) gomoku (five in line) board game
- granatier (>= 4:4.11.3) Bomberman clone
- kapman (>= 4:4.11.3) Pac-Man clone
- katomic (>= 4:4.11.3) atomix puzzle game
- kblackbox (>= 4:4.11.3) Black Box puzzle game
- kblocks (>=4:4.11.3) falling blocks game
- kbounce (>= 4:4.11.3) Jezzball arcade game
- kbreakout (>= 4:4.11.3) ball and paddle game
- kdiamond (>=4:4.11.3) three-in-a-row game
- kfourinline (>= 4:4.11.3) Connect Four game
- kgoldrunner (>= 4:4.11.3) Lode Runner arcade game
- kigo (>= 4:4.11.3) go game
- killbots (>= 4:4.11.3) port of the classic BSD console game robots
- kiriki (>= 4:4.11.3) Yahtzee dice game
- kjumpingcube (>= 4:4.11.3) simple tactical game
- klickety (>= 4:4.11.3) SameGame puzzle game
- klines (>= 4:4.11.3) color lines game
- kmahjongg (>= 4:4.11.3) mahjongg solitaire game
- kmines (>= 4:4.11.3) minesweeper game
- knavalbattle (>= 4:4.11.3) battleship board game
- knetwalk (>= 4:4.11.3) wire puzzle game
- kolf (>= 4:4.11.3) miniature golf game
- kollision (>= 4:4.11.3) simple ball dodging game
- konquest (>= 4:4.11.3) simple turn-based strategy game
- kpat (>= 4:4.11.3) solitaire card games
- kreversi (>= 4:4.11.3) reversi board game
- kshisen (>= 4:4.11.3) Shisen-Sho solitaire game
- ksirk (>= 4:4.11.3) Risk strategy game
- ksnakeduel (>= 4:4.11.3) Tron-like snakerace game
- kspaceduel (>= 4:4.11.3) SpaceWar! arcade game
- ksquares (>= 4:4.11.3) Dots and Boxes game
- ksudoku (>= 4:4.11.3) Sudoku puzzle game and solver
- ktuberling (>= 4:4.11.3) stamp drawing toy
- kubrick (>=4:4.11.3) game based on Rubik's Cube
- lskat (>= 4:4.11.3) Lieutnant Skat card game
- palapeli (>= 4:4.11.3) jigsaw puzzle game
- picmi (>=4:4.11.3) Number logic game
- kajongg (>= 4:4.11.3) classical Mah Jongg
  game

All of these packages can be installed in 15.04 using...

```
sudo apt-get install bomber bovo granatier kapman katomic kblackbox kblocks kbounce kbreakout kdiamond kfourinline kgoldrunner kigo killbots kiriki kjumpingcube klickety klines kmahjongg kmines knavalbattle knetwalk kolf kollision konquest kpat kreversi kshisen ksirk ksnakeduel kspaceduel ksquares ksudoku ktuberling kubrick lskat palapeli picmi kajongg
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent addition to my answer, @pj-singh .